# css does not work in .net core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

My css files dont work after I publish my site in .net core

I have registered my static folder which is lib under the wwwroot, and despite deleting all files and rebuilding it, it still does not work. I have tried using /wwwroot/lib and just /wwwroot nothing works

```
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot"))
        ,
    RequestPath = new PathString("/wwwroot")
});
```

Comment: wwwroot is the static content home by default. How are you accessing the css files in your views ?

Comment: Why are you calling `UseStaticFiles` twice?

Comment: @shyju   see my code  <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
        <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/CParts2018.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/CParts2018.js"></script>
    </environment>

Comment: @davidg I tried once, and saw a comment online saying I could call it twice. Nothing is working

Comment: Do you have `css/site.css` inside the `wwwroot` directory ? That code should work fine. When you say it does not work, are you getting a 404 to load that css file in your browser ?

Comment: Also when i add the RequestPath to the watch window, I get the error  

RequestPath error CS0103: The name 'RequestPath' does not exist in the current context

Comment: You don't need the second call to `UseStaticFiles`.  Get rid of it.

Comment: I have moved the css file which is cparts.css and it does not work. Here is my latest code

Comment: RequestPath = new PathString("/lib/bootstrap/dist/css")

Comment: I found the error. It was the way I declared the css, I declared it in the include in development

Comment: So I added it to the  <environment exclude="Development"> section in my layout page and it worked. thanks

Comment: Did you check bundleconfig.json. You may need  to include your css files there otherwise it will not include in your production builds.